# The iTunes Store has no record of past Audiobook purchases

Tags: itunes, mac-appstore

Two or three years ago, I purchased four audio books. I recently was forced to restore my iPod, losing all content. When I went to my computer to restore the content, I found that, although the book artwork was there, the audio was missing. I work in Afghanistan and have limited internet access. I am now in Dubai, UAE on vacation and when I went online to the iTunes store there is nothing in my purchase history. How do I get those books back?

Comment: maybe there is changing in your iStore country, if i'm not wrong your purchase only available in specific country. Depend on what country you use when the first time you brought that product.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you to take your question directly to the [iTunes Store personnel](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact/), they are the ones who keep track of user accounts and purchases made.

You will want to be able to provide them the billing address and payment method you used for those purchases. Also, if you can find any of the invoices that Apple emails between a few hours to a few days after each purchase - you can also let the Apple Store support person you contact that email in case your Apple ID is different than the email on file.

Comment: Just to be clear - this site is not in any way run by Apple. The small print at the bottom of most non-mobile web pages here states: "This site is not affiliated with or endorsed by Apple Inc. in any way."